# Django: How to include several views/classes in the same url?

Tags: django, url, redirect, indexing, view

I would like to have both a contact form, a newsletter form and a photo slider/portofolio in index.html. Everything drawn into this page only.

Am I correct to assume it has something to do With "URL dispatcher" in the documentation? And could someone please help me with some examples on how to point everything to the same URL?

Want everything to redirect back to the index when done, after email has been sent, after registering for newsletter and so on. Just to explain better what I actually mean here as I don't have the knowledge to do it in correct terminology.

Thanks in advance for all the help I can get.

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with the URL dispatcher. A URL can only point to one single view.

Comment: Ok, thank you. But how could I include more than one class or app in the same url/page? Maybe I misunderstand the concept. But it is possible what I want?

Answer (score 0):

As a possible solution you can create index page with multiple forms. Each form will redirect on post to it own view, for example:

First form:

```
<form action="{% url 'myapp:index_one' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

Second form:

```
<form action="{% url 'myapp:index_two' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

In each view you create all the forms and pass them to index.html

```
def index_one():
    indexForm1 = index_form1()
    indexForm2 = index_form2()

    if request.POST:
        indexForm = index_form1(request.POST, request.FILES)
        //process first form here

    //load index.html and pass context with forms
```

In second view you do the same but on POST you process another form:

```
def index_two():
    indexForm1 = index_form1()
    indexForm2 = index_form2()

    if request.POST:
        indexForm2 = index_form2(request.POST, request.FILES)
        //process second form here

    //load index.html and pass context with forms
```

I have such solution in production and it is working fine.